# How to resequence all dates in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Godaddy Hosting,
PHP 5,
MySQL 5.0,
Wordpress 3.3.1

I set all my posts to the same publish date and it wiped out the next post / previous post links. There were thousands.

Is there a way to change the post_date in phpMyAdmin, so that the post_date is

```
2012-20-02 15:24:40
2012-20-02 15:24:41
2012-20-02 15:24:42
2012-20-02 15:24:43
2012-20-02 15:24:44
```

etc...?
...or something similar, as long as they are different.

I've tried this in MySQL / phpMyAdmin

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '2012-02-18 01:47:50'
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date = ( @Date := @Date +1 )
```

but it errors out.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to     your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '2012-02-18 01:47:50'
UPDATE wp_posts SET p' at line 1
```

Any hints or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [MySQL Date function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) would be the place to start.

Comment: This is exactly why I always do my select first, then erase over select and replace with update, and always add a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the wp_posts table has a post_id field which is the unqiue identifier for each post (you may need to change the column there if its different)

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date = DATE_ADD(post_date,INTERVAL post_id SECOND)
```

The above query will add a number of seconds based on the post_id value which means that the latest posts will have later dates than the earlier posts. If you want the reverse then use DATE_SUB

Comment: That worked great.  I only had to change post_id to id. Here is the final code that worked. `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date = DATE_ADD(post_date,INTERVAL id SECOND)`  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Declare @auto Int 
Set @auto = 0 
Update tblName set post_date=DATEADD(minute,(@auto * @increment),
convert(datetime, @post_date)),
@auto = (@auto + 1) 
Where posted_id=@posted_id
```